# Calculating the variance of vibration acceleration

Tags: noise, measurement

In a vibration measurement of a rotating blade, I have the following information. The vibration signal is measured using a ICP accelerometer which has the following specification

- Measurement range: 50g
- Sensitivity: 100 mV/g
- Thus max output voltage: ±5V
- Broadband resolution: 100*1e-6g

The variance of the acquired signal is

\begin{align}\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\Var_{aq}=\Var_{acl}+\Var_{adc}+\Var_{sig}\sim6.2e-4 g
\end{align}

$\Var_{acl}$: variance of noise in the accelerometer
$\Var_{adc}$: variance of the ADC noise (quantization, jitter)
$\Var_{sig}$ variance of the vibration acceleration of the blade.

Assuming that $\Var_{acl}\sim\sqrt{\text{broadband noise of accelerometer}} = 1e-8 \text{g}_\text{rms}$

From the specification sheet of the ADC, for the used input gain of 30db and sampling frequency = 51.2Hz, the **var_adc** = 1e-12 **V_rms**

Can anyone please help , how can I calculate the variance of vibtation acceleration of the blade i.e **var_sig**

Comment: what does your ~ mean? Proportionality? Why would a variance be proportional to the square root of noise? (I guess that means noise amplitude?) Or what do you mean with "broadband noise": a power? A power density?

Comment: ~  means the summation is approximately equal to 6.2e-4. accelerometer sensor noise is defined as broadband resolution. some literature call it broadband resolution and some  call it broadband noise.

Comment: hm, but a resolution is an amplitude quantity, and a variance is most definitely a quadratic amplitude quantity, so it really can't be that Var_acl = \sqrt{resolution}. Something's not right here.